# Using enum in namespace

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using enumeration in namespace in my [code](http://cpp.sh/8gwnb)

```
namespace Statusss
{
enum  Statuss
    {
    Out = -1,
    Ok = 0,
    Busy = 1,
    Error = 2,
    Nor = 3
    };
}


void tst()
{
  int status =0;

  Statusss::Statuss mystatus = static_cast<Statusss::Statuss>(status);

  if (mystatus == (Statusss::Statuss::Ok))
  {
    std::cout << "Ok\n";
  } else std::cout << "Other\n";

}
```

It works fine in simple console application. But if I place this code in GUI Qt widget application I have error:

```
'Statusss::Statuss' is not a class or namespace
   if (mystatus == (Statusss::Statuss::Ok))
                              ^
```

Why I'm getting this?

Comment: Did you tell Qt to use C++11 or higher?

Comment: Different compiler options, presumably. `Statusss::Statuss::Ok` is not valid code. The value names of the enumeration are directly in the namespace: the old style enumeration doesn't work as a scope.

Comment: if  namespace Statusss defined in other header file then have you included it in your application /

Comment: Use `enum class Statuss { ... };`  instead of `namespace Statusss { enum Statuss { ... }; }`.

Comment: I did not tell Qt use C++11? How to use `Statusss::Statuss::Ok` in old style?

Comment: @vico - You can't without C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct name for that symbol is

```
Statusss::Ok
```

In a traditional C-style enum, like the one you show here, the enum type is not part of the scope.